How can I query a few levels deep in AngularFIre?
I am trying to get some data from a database where I want only objects that contains a certain key/value pair to be returned.
I am using RTDB with Angular Fire.
Lets say this is the data
{
"times": {
"tuesday":[
{"moods":[
{"play" : "good"}
{"play" : "good"}
{"play" : "bad"}
{"play" : "okay"}
{"play" : "just right"}
]}
]
}
}

In Angular I have a fetch for the database that uses switch map to change the current path annd update
 this.items$ = this.a_s.xc$.pipe(switchMap((x) => {
  return this.db.list('times'+x).valueChanges();   
  }));

then I subscribe
    this.items$.subscribe({next: (value) => {
      console.log(value)
            }
          });



What I would like is to get all the objects where play == good . That's in Times/Tuesday/Moods
I tried using some example I found online but quickly realized angular only allow those 1 level deep, for sure this is possible ?

Firebase has about 20 products, of which 3 are databases these days. Can you clarify which specific Firebase product you are asking about? Also note that we have no idea how the fixtures in your code related to the data, and what x is.

fixtures supposed to be part of the path to the list. I am using RTDB

"part of the path to the list" is not clear to me and changing it to path in the code doesn't help as path is also not present in the sample JSON you provide. Please make sure that the code and the data in your question match up.
